# Explain Swift Iterators

Tags: swift, generator

There’s very little up-to-date guidance on how to make generators in Swift (or *iterators* as they’re apparently called in Swift), especially if you are new to the language. Why are there so many generator types like `AnyIterator` and `UnfoldSequence`? Why doesn’t the following code, which should yield from a sequence of either individual `Int`s or Arrays of `Int`s, work?

```
func chain(_ segments: Any...) -> AnyIterator<Int>{
    return AnyIterator<Int> {
        for segment in segments {
            switch segment {
            case let segment as Int:
                return segment
            case let segment as [Int]:
                for i in segment {
                    return i
                }
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let G = chain(array1, 42, array2)
while let g = G.next() {
    print(g)
}
```

The way I understand it, `AnyIterator` is supposed to take the closure in the `{}`s and turn it into the `.next()` method in the returned generator, but it doesn’t seem to be working. Or should I be using `UnfoldSequence` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203182/fibonacci-numbers-generator-in-swift-3) instead. I’m very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `next()` method of `AnyIterator` calls the given closure.
And in your code, that closure returns the *same first element on each call,* because it does not remember what elements have been returned already.

If Swift had a `yield` statement like Python or C# then things would be easier: you could `yield segment` or `yield i` and are done.

But – unfortunately? – Swift has no `yield` statement, which means
that the closure must explicitly manage some state in order to resume the iteration
with the next element on each call.

One possibility would be to maintain two indices, one for
the current segment and one for the current element within
a segment if that is an array:

```
func chain(_ segments: Any...) -> AnyIterator<Int> {
    var currentSegment = 0 // index of current segment
    var currentElement = 0 // index of current element within current segment
    return AnyIterator<Int> {
        while currentSegment < segments.count {
            let next = segments[currentSegment]
            switch next {
            case let value as Int:
                currentSegment += 1
                return value
            case let segment as [Int]:
                if currentElement < segment.count {
                    let val = segment[currentElement]
                    currentElement += 1
                    return val
                }
                currentSegment += 1
                currentElement = 0
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This can be generalized to arbitrarily nested arrays:

```
func chain(_ segments: Any...) -> AnyIterator<Int> {
    var stack: [(Any, Int)] = [(segments, 0)]
    return AnyIterator<Int> {
        while let (next, idx) = stack.popLast() {
            switch next {
            case let value as Int:
                return value
            case let segments as [Any]:
                if idx < segments.count {
                    stack.append((segments, idx + 1))
                    stack.append((segments[idx], 0))
                }
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The still-to-be-processed arrays are on the stack together with
their current index. The arrays themselves are not modified,
so that the copy is cheap.

Example:

```
let G = chain([1, 2, [3]], 4, [5, 6, [], 7])
while let g = G.next() {
    print(g)
}
// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

See also [Implementing recursive generator for simple tree structure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278610/implementing-recursive-generator-for-simple-tree-structure-in-swift) for more
approaches to recursively enumerate a tree-like structure.

Comment: so this creates a copy of the array? isn’t that something generators are used to avoid?

Comment: @taylorswift: How large is your array? Does it matter? – But as I said, it surely can be improved, it was meant to explain the general idea. – You could for example (in the first method) store the index of the current segment and the index of the current element within  the current segment if that is an array.

Comment: often we want to use generators to build a joined or flattened array out of many pieces “at once”, to bypass slow extend methods in the high level language. If the array gets copied we are better off just using repeated array concatenation? Or is that exactly what you’re supposed to do in Swift and i am thinking too much like a python programmer

Comment: the idea here with these kinds of generators is the generator does all the work of locating the items that are supposed to go into the array, and then the copy operations to actually build the array can be done in one pass

Comment: @taylorswift: The first method was indeed not optimal. I have replaced it with a method which keeps only two indices.

Comment: i suppose the new question should be then, is using a generator any faster than just repeatedly appending/extending a Swift array

Comment: @taylorswift: If you want to create a flattened "real array" with all elements then I *assume* that there will be no difference. If you just want to *iterate* over all elements, without the need to  them in an array, then a generator or (lazy) sequence would be faster, at least if you have many objects. – But yes, that would be a different question.

Comment: ... (cross-post ellipsis) the _"if Swift had a yield"_ statement was the reason of me wanting to (attempt to) use the `sequence(state:,next:)` to try to somewhat emulate that in the context of the example is this Q&A. Anyhow, the `sequence(state:, next:)` (without a `state` closure :( ) function can be used as a [slightly modified alternative](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/3eda3e2540b31486d5728b2fa574e8af) to the simple stack solution of yours above.

Comment: @dfri: I assume that you chose to reverse the arrays because removing the *last* element is faster than removing the first? An ArraySlice might be an alternative. I have also thought of just keeping a stack of indices (as a generalization of the first method).

Comment: @MartinR exactly, the `insert(...)` methods are generally `O(n)` whereas appending is amortized `O(1)` (with an extra single initial `reversed` on array top level). And partly for the semantics of a stack. But if performance is really an issue, working with indices will probably prove to be most performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out this custom implementation of an iterator as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67215766/5867877

```
class ArrayIterator<T>{

private var array : [T] = []
private var stepSize: Int = 10
private var head: Int = 0

var hasNext: Bool {
    get {
        return head < array.count
    }
}
class func from(array: [T], stepSize size: Int = 10, startingAt startIndex: Int = 0) -> ArrayIterator<T>{
    
    let a = ArrayIterator<T>()
    a.array = array
    a.stepSize = size
    a.head = startIndex
    return a
}

func next() -> Array<T>? {
    guard head < array.count else {
        return nil
    }
    
    defer {
        head = head + stepSize
    }
    
    guard stepSize < array.count else {
        return array
    }
    
    if let _ = array[safe: (head + stepSize - 1)] {
        return Array(array[head..<head + stepSize])
        
    } else {
        let remaider = (head + stepSize - 1) % array.count
        return Array(array[head..<(head + stepSize - 1 - remaider)])
    }
}
```